# Core Data NSRangeException Crash in multi threaded block

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I have a core data structure where contacts are parsed from server and associated with an Account entity.To create crash I:
1. login with user A and create a contact
2. login with user B and crash occurs.

Obviously there is an empty NSArray causing this crash.

The crash occurs while looping through each of the contacts in the server data with performBlock:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *mainMOC = self.managedObjectContext;
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    //NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
    [moc setParentContext:mainMOC];
    [moc setUndoManager:nil];


    BCRAccount *account2 = (BCRAccount*)[moc objectWithID:[self.loggedInAccount objectID]];

    //[moc performBlockAndWait:^{
    [moc performBlock:^{
         //parse each contact
```

Also i call a fetch request for each contact in a separate method that references the child managed object:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[BCRContact entityName]];
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = childmoc;

NSArray *fectchresult = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
```

I'm wondering if it is a to-many or to-one relationship problem. There must be some left over data from the first login that is contributing to the 2nd login crash.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 15 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18be921c0 0x18a8cc55c 0x18bdfd3dc 0x10024c154 0x1920301b4 0x1920303e4 0x19201d98c 0x192035448 0x191dd17e8 0x191cea220 0x18f1aa188 0x18f19ee64 0x18f19ed24 0x18f11b7ec 0x18f142c58 0x18f143678 0x18be3f7dc 0x18be3d40c 0x18be3d89c 0x18bd6c048 0x18d7f2198 0x191d582fc 0x191d53034 0x10008e578 0x18ad505b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

lastly before all of this parsing happens i see this error as well when a separate service is called:
2016-11-11 12:22:34.660266 AtEventUniversal[2223:781261] invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.

Thanks for any tips on this mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a situation where you dont know whats causing the crash, you should use `Exception Breakpoint...` and `Symbolic breakpoint...` to catch the exception.

[image: screenshot]